# Thread-safety mutable cross-references in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex, pyo3

I want to implement two different structures that have references to each other, can mutate each other, and are thread-safety.

I can introduce the following example:

```rust
pub struct Player {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    game: Option<Game>, // Reference to `Game`
}

impl Player {
    pub fn new(x: f32, y: f32) -> Self {    
        Player { x, y, game: None}
    }

    // Some functions that can change `self`, `game`, and `map`
}

pub struct Game {
    pub map: GameMap,
    players: Vec<Player>, // Reference to `Player`
}

impl Game {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Game { map: GameMap::new(), players: Vec::new()}
    }

    pub fn register_player(&mut self, player: Player) {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a similar interface:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut p1 = Player::new(0.0, 0.0);
    let mut p2 = Player::new(100.0, 100.0);

    let mut game = Game::new();
    game.register_player(p1);
    game.register_player(p2);

    p1.forward();  // changes its coordinates using `map` from `game`
    p2.shoot();  // changes the `map` and possibly another player
}
```

I can't use `std::rc::Rc` and `std::cell::RefCell` because my goal is to write thread-safety code. I tried `std::sync::{Arc, Mutex}`, but it's not succeeded yet. How could I solve this challenge?

---

UPD Here I add the code where I tried to use mutex

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub struct Player {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    game: Option<Arc<Mutex<Game>>>,
}

impl Player {
    pub fn create(x: f32, y: f32) -> Arc<Mutex<Self>> {
        let mut player = Player {
            x,
            y,
            game: None,
        };
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(player))
    }

    pub fn mount_game(&mut self, game: Arc<Mutex<Game>>) {
        self.game = Some(game);
    }
}

pub struct Game {
    players: Vec<Arc<Mutex<Player>>>,
}

impl Game {
    pub fn create() -> Arc<Mutex<Self>> {
        let mut game = Game {
            players: Vec::new(),
        };
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(game))
    }

    pub fn register_player(&self, game_arc: Arc<Mutex<Self>>, player_arc: Arc<Mutex<Player>>) {
        let mut game = game_arc.lock().unwrap();
        game.players.push(Arc::clone(&player_arc));
        player_arc.lock().unwrap().mount_game(Arc::clone(&game_arc));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p1 = Player::create(0.0, 0.0);
    let mut p2 = Player::create(0.0, 0.0);
    let mut game = Game::create();
    game.lock().unwrap().register_player(Arc::clone(&game), Arc::clone(&p1));
    game.lock().unwrap().register_player(Arc::clone(&game), Arc::clone(&p2));
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you're using `Arc<Mutex<_>>` because that is the right type for thread-safe interior mutability. (Though there may still be other types that would work better for your use case.)

Comment: @cdhowie It's not compilling, I don't know how to code this correctly yet. If you could provide an example of how to use `Arc<Mutex<_>>` with my context to code mutable cross-references, it'd be unbelievable

Comment: Can you _show us the code that's not compiling?_

Comment: @cdhowie Ok, I've updated the question body

Comment: You aren't cloning the arc pointing to the game in register player.

Comment: I cannot compile the code due to syntax errors, missing type definitions, and missing `use` declarations. Please create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that I can copy and paste _as is._

Comment: Ideally, try to reproduce your error in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/), then copy the corresponding code in your question, _along with the complete error message_ and a link to the playground.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question body again. Now code can be compelled, but it's not working correctly (I suppose here I have a deadlock) and it doesn't have the interface I'd like to have. Hopefully it can illustrate the problem I face 

Comment: Is [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2bd08fa5fe49bc4033f9cee5c0d3fe80) what you are looking for?

Comment: Note that using `Arc` for both is wrong and will lead to a memory leak. Use `Weak` for one.

Comment: @Jmb I think it is. Could you please explain when you use just `Arc<T>` and when `Arc<Mutex<T>>`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Could you please explain why it leads to a memory leak and how to use `Weak` correctly in this case or provide a reference to an explanation?

Comment: @Jmb I found out that's not what I'm looking for because `Player` can't change `Game` in your example. Only `Game` can change `Player`'s state there

Comment: @ChayimFriedman good point, @VladimirAlinsky the logical place to put the `Weak` is inside `Player` like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=a0db36492ce11f2419bbdb572ab8cd77)

Comment: @VladimirAlinsky `Player` can change `Game` by locking the inner `Mutex`. Although if you have more fields inside `Game`, it might be easier to implement a trait on `Mutex<Game>` like this: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=fd8e01ead7cdf4075aa8787195155c01).

Comment: Yes! That's what I need! @Jmb if you post the last one as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one. Thank you Jmb and others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted deadlocks because you lock the game mutex twice:

- Once in `main` when you call `game.lock()`,
- And then in `register_player` when you call `game_arc.lock()`.

Moreover from an API standpoint, needing to pass the game twice to `register_player` (once as `self` and once as `game_arc`) is pretty awkward.

Now if we get rid of the mutex around `Game` so that we have an `Arc<Game>`, then we can declare `register_player` as:

```
pub fn register_player (self: &Arc<Game>, player_arc: Arc<Mutex<Player>>)
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2bd08fa5fe49bc4033f9cee5c0d3fe80)

But then we need to put a `Mutex` inside `Game` if we want to be able to mutate it:

```
pub struct Game {
    players: Mutex<Vec<Arc<Mutex<Player>>>>,
    // Here: ^^^^^
}
```

In this case `Game` contains a single field so it's easy, but assuming your game state is more complex, this becomes painful to use.

It would be nice if we could tell the compiler that `register_player` takes an `&Arc<Mutex<Self>>`, but unfortunately we can only use types that `Deref` to `Self` and `Mutex` can't (*). We also can't add the `register_player` method directly on `Mutex<Game>` like this:

```
// Not allowed:
impl Mutex<Game> {
    pub fn register_player (self: &Arc<Mutex<Game>>, player_arc: Arc<Mutex<Player>>) {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

because `Mutex` is a foreign type. We can however fake it using an [extension trait](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-extension-traits.html):

```
pub trait GameExt {
    pub fn register_player (self: &Arc<Self>, player_arc: Arc<Mutex<Player>>);
}

impl GameExt for Mutex<Game> {
    fn register_player (self: &Arc<Self>, player_arc: Arc<Mutex<Player>>) {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

Finally, having an `Arc<Player>` inside `Game` and an `Arc<Game>` inside `Player` is a bad idea because it risks introducing memory leaks: they will still refer to each other even when you drop all other references, so their respective reference counts will never reach 0 and they will never be freed. This can be avoided by replacing one of the `Arc`s by a [`Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Weak.html) pointer, which will break the cycle.

Full working example (I also removed a bunch of superfluous `mut`s since `Arc<Mutex<_>>` values don't need to be `mut` before they're locked):

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, Weak};

pub struct Player {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    game: Option<Weak<Mutex<Game>>>,
}

impl Player {
    pub fn create (x: f32, y: f32) -> Arc<Mutex<Self>> {
        let player = Player {
            x,
            y,
            game: None,
        };
        Arc::new (Mutex::new (player))
    }

    pub fn mount_game (&mut self, game: Arc<Mutex<Game>>) {
        self.game = Some (Arc::downgrade (&game));
    }
    
    pub fn modify_game_state (&self) {
        self.game.as_ref().unwrap().upgrade().unwrap().lock().unwrap().state = 42;
    }
}

pub struct Game {
    state: i32,
    players: Vec<Arc<Mutex<Player>>>,
}

impl Game {
    pub fn new() -> Arc<Mutex<Self>> {
        let game = Game {
            state: 0,
            players: Vec::new(),
        };
        Arc::new (Mutex::new (game))
    }
}

pub trait GameExt {
    fn register_player (self: &Arc<Self>, player_arc: Arc<Mutex<Player>>);
}

impl GameExt for Mutex<Game> {
    fn register_player (self: &Arc<Self>, player_arc: Arc<Mutex<Player>>) {
        player_arc.lock().unwrap().mount_game (Arc::clone(self));
        let mut game = self.lock().unwrap();
        game.players.push (player_arc);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let p1 = Player::create (0.0, 0.0);
    let p2 = Player::create (0.0, 0.0);
    let game = Game::new();
    game.register_player (p1); // or Arc::clone (&p1) if you need to use p1 later in this function
    game.register_player (Arc::clone (&p2));
    p2.lock().unwrap().modify_game_state();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=b27159d3b5a72b8dbbc80103efbd3a24)

---

(*) `Mutex<Foo>` can't `Deref` to `Foo` because it needs somewhere to put the `MutexGuard` while the reference is live, and `Deref` doesn't offer anywhere to put the guard.